# function onEdit(e) - Resolution vs Deadline - Once a task has been "Completed" with a deadline?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image][image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icPpZ.jpg)Need help, please.
I've created the below onEdit(e) script to trigger the deadline when a task is "Completed".
Now I would need a function for Resolution time (days) vs Deadline (date).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Merci

```js
function onEdit(e)   // runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //var range = e.range; 
  var aCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
  var row = aCell.getRow();
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var values = sheet.getRange(row, 3, row, 21).getValues();    //Contents of row in Array 
 
   if (sheet.getName() == 'ESCALATION')
  {
    if ((aColumn == 2) && (values[0][3] == "Completed"))  // Column B indicates (Status) and should be changed to "Completed" once a task has been finished - same time Column V should be populate which indicates  "Resolution" time in days.  

      if (values[0][13] == '' )
      { 
        aCell.setValue(e.oldValue);
        }

aCell.offset(0, 19).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CET", "dd-MMM-yyyy"))    // Column U Completed - 19
        var result = new Date();
        result.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        var target = new Date(values[0][13]); 
        target.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        var diff = ((result.valueOf() - target.valueOf())/ (1000*60*60*24));
      
        
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName ('ESCALATION'); 
  }
} 
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
```

Comment: Please post your code in your question.

Comment: Done. Can you see it and maybe you can advise me?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: In my sheet: // Column B indicates (Status) and should be changed to "Completed" once a task has been finished - same time Column V should be populated which indicates  "Resolution" time in days.  
What Am I missing in the script?

Comment: I don't follow offsite links.  Post the screen shots here.

Comment: Just updated my post with a screenshot of my google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have been testing your code and, after developing some little changes, I made it reach your goals. I can see that you already coded enough to trigger a timestamp into the cell. You only need to transform that timestamp into a day count and you are finished.

To reach that day count, it is needed to work with two different variables. One of them will be the time right now, and the other will be the case timestamp. To create the *now timestamp* you can simply use `var nowTimestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");` (please notice how I used a different date format for simplicity; you can update it with the desired specifications). The code will also need the case timestamp (Column C), to do so you only need to use: `var caseTimestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(caseDate),…,…);` (in this case `caseDate` would be the `var` with the corresponding value of Column C, obtained with [`Range.getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)).

At this point you already have a `Date` object with the current timestamp, and a second one with the *case timestamp*. Then you only need to calculate the milliseconds difference with `var delta = nowTimestamp.getTime() - caseTimestamp.getTime()` ([`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) reference). Finally, you can transform that milliseconds into a day count with `var dayCount = delta / (1000 * 3600 * 24)`. Please ask me for any clarifications if they are needed.

---

## EDIT

To add more light to my solution I want to share the [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) docs. Please read it to obtain a better grasp about date formatting in this programming language. Ideally you will modify the example `var` to adequate it to your own timestamps. In the linked docs you can find exactly how.

Comment: Hey @Jacques-Guzel, I have added the suggested var of yours - but I run into an error

Error Exception: The parameters ((class)) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.
onEdit @ Code.gs:96
Will add a screenshot to see.

Comment: This `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(caseDate));` needs to have the timezone and the format string.  You need to get used to going to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) and figuring out what parameters are needed

Comment: @ArgiHam I just updated my answer to clarify that point. Please take a look and modify the example to adequate it to your own needs.